# How to detect whether a hard drive is external USB or internal?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb

I want to detect whether a drive is external or internal. I have an SATA drive connected to a USB port through an SATA-USB adapter.

hdparm -I reports it as:

```
ATA device, with non-removable media
...
Transport: Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0.
```

It apparently gets this data directly from the drive. Is it possible for hdparm to detect the actual transport layer, instead of the one the drive reports?

I also tried `lsusb`. It doesn't seem to be useful. It is human readable, but there is no way to cross-reference its output with other device commands. Iterating through buses with `lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/...` doesn't seem appropriate, either, although maybe I could do something like `find /dev/bus | while read -r line; do if((lsusb -D $line | grep) CONTAINS SOME SUBSTRING MENTIONING THE DEVICE) then  blah  done`

`parted --list` also fails to report the fact that the external drive is running over USB:

```
Model: ADATA SU 800 (scsi)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can tell like this:

```
$ realpath /sys/block/sd*
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sdb
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sdc
```

Notes:

- If not `realpath` then `readlink` may give you a clue.
- Query about a specific device, some of them (like above) or all of them (`/sys/block/*`).
- In my Kubuntu `/sys/class/block/` contains entries for partitions as well (e.g. `sda1`).

---

POSIX solution:

```
$ for p in /sys/block/sd*; do (cd "$p" && pwd -P); done
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0/block/sdb
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sdc
```